# Unnable to read json response in reactjs

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, axios

I need to replace a value in the response ,

My Json format :

```
{"Message":"","IsSuccessful":true,"sample2.0com":["data1","data2"],"sample1.0com":["data3","data4","data5","data6"]}}
```

When I am trying to read the above response , I am facing issue

```
let sample2 = response.data.Result.sample2.0com;
```

Please give me a solution to read `sample2.0com` components from the response

Comment: Did you try this `response.data.Result['sample2.0com']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is because of your . in the sample2.0com.. you have to use the `[]` to call the property, so use `response.data.Result['sample2.0com']`, but I am not sure what is the "Result" object ... maybe you should use `response.data['sample2.0com']`

Comment: Thank u  , it worked  with response.data['sample2.0com']

Comment: Great, please mark the answer as a good one, so other peoples with the same problem will know it's a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Keys that are not valid JavaScript variable names (start with one of `a-zA-Z_$` and contain only `a-zA-Z0-9_$`) must be accessed as strings inside square brackets (`[]`).

For example: `obj.camelCase` is OK, but `obj.this key contains spaces` is not OK - it would have to be `obj['this key contains spaces']`.

Answer (score 2):

JSON objects are surrounded by curly braces `{}`.

You can access the object values by using dot `.` notation:

```
myObj = { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null };
x = myObj.name;
```

You can also access the object values by using bracket ([]) notation:

```
myObj = { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null };
x = myObj["name"];
```

Similarly you can use as like above

```
responseData = {"Message":"","IsSuccessful":true,"sample2.0com":["data1","data2"],"sample1.0com":["data3","data4","data5","data6"]}}

let sample2 = responseData["sample2.0com"];
```

This will fix yours